# How to extract path to filename

Tags: bash, path, filenames

In bash programming If `VAR="/home/somestuff/work/OutExample/Air"`,

How to get `"workOutExampleAir"` ?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you need that?

Answer (score 0):

```
 cut -f4- -d/ --output-delimiter ""  <<< "$var"
```

**cut** utility takes field from 4 with delimiter /

in *bash*

```
name=$(cut -f4- -d/ --output-delimiter ""  <<< "$var")
echo "$name"
```

Comment: Remember your quotes around parameter expansions: `<<< "$VAR"` and `echo "$NAME"`. Also you shouldn't use uppercase variable names as they are reserved to environment variables.